# Calculate probability of A knowing $P(A), P(B), P(C) \geq \frac{2}{3}, P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}$) be a probability triple and suppose $\mathbb{P}(A) \geq \frac{2}{3}, \mathbb{P}(B) \geq \frac{2}{3}, \mathbb{P}(C) \geq \frac{2}{3}$, and $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$. Calculate $\mathbb{P}(A)$.

I'm trying to use inclusion-exclusion somewhere but nothing worked so far. This is probably a correct inequality but leads me nowhere.
$$
2 - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) - \mathbb{P}(B \cap C) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap C)  \leq  \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}(C) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) - \mathbb{P}(B \cap C) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap C) \leq 1
$$

What is the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that by inclusion-exclusion, we have
$$
1\geq P(B\cup C) = P(B)+ P(C) - P(B\cap C)\\
P(B\cap C)\geq P(B) + P(C) - 1\geq \frac13
$$
By a similar argument using $A$ and $B\cap C$, we get
$$
1\geq P(A\cup (B\cap C)) = P(A) + P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)
$$
Armed with the fact that $P(A\cap B\cap C) = 0$, this simplifies to
$$
1\geq P(A) + P(B\cap C)
$$
However, $P(A)\geq \frac23$ and $P(B\cap C)\geq \frac13$. So we also have
$$
1\leq P(A) + P(B\cap C)
$$
meaning that we must in fact have 
$$
1 = P(A) + P(B\cap C)
$$
This can only be achieved with $P(A) = \frac23, P(B\cap C) = \frac13$.